# how to add property on nested object array and edit the original array?

Tags: javascript

i have been trying doing so but in the last console log I got undefined , what is wrong??

```
 dishes = dishes.map((cat) => {
      cat.map((dish) => {
        console.log("cat", dish[0], "dish", dish[1]);
         dish[1].map((element) => {
          element = { ...element, category: dish[0] };
        });
      });
    });

    console.log("dishes",dishes)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forget return the map result

```
 dishes = dishes.map((cat) => {
  return cat.map((dish) => {
    console.log("cat", dish[0], "dish", dish[1]);
    return dish[1].map((element) => ({ ...element,
      category: dish[0]
    }))
  });
});
```

Still undefined check the `dishes` array declared properly before the map

```
var dishes = [something]
```

Answer (score 0):

**You have to return something in your `map` callbacks**. When using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), you don't necessarily need to include the `return` keyword, though. In cases where you only need to return the result of an expression, you can remove the body brackets and the `return`. For example: `const addOne = a => { return a + 1 }` can be simplified to just `const addOne = a => a + 1`.

In your case, the logic might look something more like:

```js
const categories = [
  [ 'category 1', [
    { name: 'dish 1' },
    { name: 'dish 2' },
  ] ],
  [ 'category 2', [
    { name: 'dish 3' },
  ] ],
]

const dishesWithCategory = categories.flatMap(
  ([ category, dishes ]) => dishes.map(dish => ({ ...dish, category }))
)

console.log('dishes', dishesWithCategory)
```